# Uncaught ReferenceError: serialport is not defined in webpack

Tags: html, node.js, webpack

I am trying to use serialport in my web application. I am using webpack for this purpose. I have added 'serialport' in the external section of webpack configuration file. It still gives me error.

My index.js file has this in it:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')
```

In my webpack.config.js I have added:

```
    externals: {
        "serialport": serialport,
    },
```

It gives me the following error:

```
external_"serialport":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: serialport is not defined
    at eval (external_"serialport":1)
    at Object.serialport (main.js:2187)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at eval (index.js:8)
    at Object../src/index.js (main.js:2143)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:8081/webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18)
    at Object.0 (main.js:2154)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at main.js:84
```